# WordPress's wp_redirect() with add_query_arg() not updating global $_GET

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, query-string

I access the page like:
example.com?step=3
Until here, it works, if I use `$_GET['step']` its ok, its 3.

But, after step 3 do what it needs to do, I call:
`wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'step', 4 ) );`
Looking on network tab at Devtools it does access with 302 as: example.com?step=4
But at the page `$_GET['step']` is still 3! Than it enters in an infinite loop.

I logged `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and it is as expected `step=4`, but right on the next line I call `$_GET['step']` and it is 3!

When I access directly example.com?step=4 it works, `$_GET['step']` is 4, but when I use `wp_redirect();` it doesnt.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you are not clearing out the old "step" before adding the new one. `add_query_arg()` doesn't update the string, it adds to it.

So try doing something like...

```
$origURL = remove_query_arg( 'step' );

wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'step', 4, $origURL ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_redirect(esc_url(add_query_arg('step' => '4',$origURL)));